# Simple javascript to read textox values and display on a blank page

Tags: javascript, html, input, textbox

I need a simple javascript that reads the value of the textbox (input) and possibly save it to a txt file or display on a blank page.

Comment: Do you have any code to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function getdata()
{
    var val=document.getElementById('t1').value;
    var win=open("");
    win.document.write(val);

}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="t1" type="text" />
<input id="B1" type="button" value="getdata"  onclick="getdata()"/>
</body>

</html>
```